# Using curl on an online compiler

Tags: c++, linux, libcurl

I have a Linux based c++ program but no Linux at home. I know most of the C++ online compilers are Linux based but I'm having some trouble.   The program uses curl to get info from a website.  Yet when I try to run it, I get:

```
fatal error: 'curl/curl.h' file not found
#include <curl/curl.h>
```

I know curl needs to be loaded an included in the compilation (`-lcurl`) but I don't know of an online compiler that has curl.  I don't know how to make any of the online compilers load/use/compile with curl.

Several different online compilers.  Cannot change compilation arguments.

Comment: If you're on Windows 10/11, have you considered using [WSL2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install)? Also, something like GitHub Codespaces _might_ work. If not, doing something like setting up a Digital Ocean or Azure cloud VM and then using VS Code to access it remotely might work too. Be careful with that if you try, though. Those can get _quite_ expensive depending on how you use them and how it's configured.

Comment: Sounds like you need to install the curl dev libraries?

Comment: @cocomac - If you read what I wrote, this is for a LINUX application.  I have the Windows version working.

Comment: @ Robert - That is exactly the problem.  How do install the libraries on a free, online server that lets me compile code?  They don't let you just load anything.

Comment: I second @cocomac's recommendation to use WSL2.